# copy large directory/files to s3 bucket from server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, copy, storage, large-files

How can I copy large a large directory/file to an AWS s3 bucket and which storage class do I have to opt for that is cost-effective ?? say, my file is a backup file.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to copy/backup a large amount of data, then s3 is a good option. AWS provides up to 5GB of free storage on a free tier account.
if you are storing data that is not frequently used, then GLACIER is an excellent choice as it's pretty cost-effective.

s3 command to copy files from server/loacal machine to aws s3 bucket:

```
aws s3 sync /your/source/path/dir/file <S3URI> --storage-class GLACIER --recursive
```

aws s3 snyc command eg :

```
`aws s3 sync /home/myname/backup-imp s3://cs*****kup/cst*****kups/ --storage-class GLACIER --recursive`
```

Note: your AWS-CLI version should be greater than 1.14
check aws-cli version :
`aws --version`